# any tools/sites/algorithms to decipher garbled text based on improper hand position on a keyboard?

Tags: cipher, reference-request

Not sure if this is the proper place to ask, but I sometimes come across garbled text (see example below). My suspicion is that the garbled text is due to a person temporarily placing their hands in the wrong position on a keyboard. I'm wondering if there are any algorithms/sites/resources that are specifically designed to decipher this type of inadvertent "cipher."

Sample text:
*"if the device or further details are received at a later date a suptphlee mpernotdaulc tm eudpwoant cwhh iwcihl lt hbies smeendtw>atch is based has been received, however, "*

Obviously, I can make educated guesses based on the characters, but I'm wondering if anyone has developed a systematic method of correcting this type of suspected error.

edit: I selected @JProblems answer because it specifically addressed my question about a tool for deciphering keyboard shifts. However, it turns out that my guess (keyboard shift) was incorrect. It seems that the text got garbled by interleaving of letters mid-sentence. See below. I have no idea how that could happen in a piece of electronic text. I only figured it out after trying JProblems suggested tool (which didn't work). Then I stared at the text for several minutes and it jumped out at me.

`suptphlee mpernotdaulc tm eudpwoant cwhh iwcihl lt hbies smeendtw>atch`

`t h e   p r o d u c t   u p o n   w h i c h   t h i s  m e d w atch`

`sup p l e m e n t a l   m e d w a t c h   w i l l   b e  s e n t`

So, the sentence is basically saying, *"if the device or further details are received at a later date a **supplemental medwatch will be sent. the product upon which this medwatch** is based has been received, however."*

Comment: This may be a little naive, but isn't this what autocorrect spellcheckers in word processing software, phones etc do?

Comment: Just curious, what would be the correct message for the example you give?

Comment: @justhalf I don't know. I don't even know if the error is due to a mis-positioning of hands on a keyboard (just a suspicion), but the general error of misplaced hands seems like it would be common.

Comment: @long I don't think I've ever seen autocorrect/spellcheckers correct for the type of shift that I describe (although I think it would be useful). As noted in another comment, I'm not even sure if the text that I posted is due to improper hand position or something else. Oh well.

Comment: Well, then can you give another example which exemplify what you mean by improper hand positioning? Regarding autocorrect, from my experience, they take keyboard distance into account, although I'm not sure whether they will correct whole word shift error. Like "error" -> "rttot" (left hand improperly positioned, right hand ok)

Comment: @justhalf Sorry. I don't have another example. This is just a piece of text I came across yesterday while reviewing a medical document. It looks like someone had a seizure mid-sentence and then recovered. I've seen similar types of text before and I was mostly wondering if anyone had developed a systematic algorithm of trying to decipher text based on shifting hand-position relative to the US keyboard. Like I said, it's not clear that my suspicion is correct in this case, but the idea just got me thinking more generally about this type of "decoding." Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Could it be an OCR error rather than a typing error?

Comment: @2012rcampion Turns out it was an "interleaving" of characters (see my edited question). I'm not even sure how that could have happened, but it looks like it did. For anyone who is interested, I got the text from an FDA database related to medical device malfunctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dcode has an engine for cracking "Keyboard shift" ciphers, which is a systematic shift of all intended letters along a particular keyboard layout. You can specify both language and keyboard layout as parameters. You can try it here: https://www.dcode.fr/keyboard-shift-cipher

Comment: Thank you. Very cool that someone did that. For anyone who cares, I figured it out. It wasn't a keyboard shift. it was some problem with every other letter. I will edit my question to show the "decipher."